# How A ,B and S communicate in java in Socket programming?

Tags: java

How client A send message to Client B and B send Message to Server S.And also how communication takes place between A and B?I have tried and solved problem for two party i.e single client and single server.  I have tried in the following way

```
//Server
public class DateServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
                    listener.getLocalPort() + "...");

                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}

//Client
public class DateClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
            "running the date service on port 9090:");
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090);
        BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        //System.exit(0);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

How communication takes palce between client in java socket programming . But i am not getting idea how communication takes place between A , B and S.I have tried too much but not succeeded.I waiting  for best answer

Comment: In this case, `B` should be your server and `A` and `C` should be your clients

Comment: Sockets are used to send data from one place to another. As there are nearly infinite possible implementations and designs, it's up to you to work out how you want to do that to best achieve your goals. When you are having a specific problem, feel free to come back here and ask about it.

Comment: My main problem is Client A send message to Client B then B send message from A and his message to server S.Also B send Message to A .This is my architecture that  i have to implements .

Comment: In such case make A,B,C as servers each having two ports, for serving the connections between them in your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MultiThreading concept. You can create two threads in server for accepting the incoming connections from A and B. you need to open two ports in server for clients A and B.

Comment: how communication takes palce between clients A and B

Comment: If A wants to communicate with B, A needs to send the message to server and server passes the messagge to B.

Comment: My main problem is Client A send message to Client B then B send message from A and his message to server S. S send message to B .Also B send Message to A .This is my architecture that i have to implements .

Answer (score 0):

The architecture depends on your need. If you want to establish a connection from X to Y, then Y needs to have a listening port. Thus B needs to listen for incoming connections. Just like S. S needs to listen for incoming traffic as well

Note that this is just one case. The architecture would depend on your requirements.